# How to obtain a tree for a higher-kinded type parameter in a scala macro

Tags: scala, scala-macros, higher-kinded-types, scala-reflect

I'm trying to write a macro to simplify some monad-related code (I'm using cats 1.6.0 for the Monads). For now I just want to be able to write `lift[F](a)` where `F` is a unary type constructor, and have that expand to `a.pure[F]`. Seems simple enough, but I can't get it working.

For now I have this code to help with type inference:

```scala
object Macros {
  class LiftPartiallyApplied[F[_]] {
    def apply[A](a: A): F[A] = macro MacroImpl.liftImpl[F, A]
  }

  def lift[F[_]] = new LiftPartiallyApplied[F]
}
```

And for the actual implementation of the macro:

```scala
object MacroImpl {
  def liftImpl[F[_], A](c: blackbox.Context)(a: c.Tree)(implicit tt: c.WeakTypeTag[F[_]]): c.Tree = {
    import c.universe._
    q"$a.pure[${tt.tpe.typeConstructor}]"
  }
}
```

Now I can call the macro like this `lift[List](42)` and it'll expand to `42.pure[List]`, great. But when I call it with a more complicated type, like `lift[({type F[A] = Either[String, A]})#F](42)`, It'll expand to `42.pure[Either]`, which is obviously broken, because `Either` is a binary type constructor and not a unary one. The problem is I just don't know what to put there instead of `${tt.tpe.typeConstructor}`…

// edit: since people apparently have trouble reproducing the problem, I've made a complete repository:
https://github.com/mberndt123/macro-experiment
I will now try to figure out what the difference between Dmytro's and my own project is.

Comment: Possibly related: https://github.com/non/kind-projector

Comment: @MatthiasBerndt I guess I found your issue. Don't put `Main` and `Macros` to the same compilation unit.

Comment: Upvoted for the `typeConstructor` method. Was searching for it a lot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't put `Main` and `Macros` to the same compilation unit.

---

> But when I call it with a more complicated type, like `lift[({type F[A] = Either[String, A]})#F](42)`, It'll expand to `42.pure[Either]`

Can't reproduce.

For me `lift[List](42)` produces (with `scalacOptions += "-Ymacro-debug-lite"`)

```
Warning:scalac: 42.pure[List]
TypeApply(Select(Literal(Constant(42)), TermName("pure")), List(TypeTree()))
```

at compile time and `List(42)` at runtime.

`lift[({ type F[A] = Either[String, A] })#F](42)` produces

```
Warning:scalac: 42.pure[[A]scala.util.Either[String,A]]
TypeApply(Select(Literal(Constant(42)), TermName("pure")), List(TypeTree()))
```

at compile time and `Right(42)` at runtime.

This is my project https://gist.github.com/DmytroMitin/334c230a4f2f1fd3fe9e7e5a3bb10df5

---

Why do you need macros? Why can't you write

```
import cats.Applicative 
import cats.syntax.applicative._ 

class LiftPartiallyApplied[F[_]: Applicative] { 
  def apply[A](a: A): F[A] = a.pure[F] 
} 

def lift[F[_]: Applicative] = new LiftPartiallyApplied[F]
```

?

Comment: I need macros because I'm planning some more advanced syntactic transformation on the `a` Tree that cannot be done with regular functions etc.

Answer (score 2):

Allright, I found out what the problem was.

Macros need to be compiled separately from their use sites. I thought that this meant that `Macros` needs to be compiled separately from `MacroImpl`, so I put those in separate sbt subprojects, and I called the macro in the project where `Macros` is defined. But what it in fact means is that *calls* of the macro need to be compiled separately from its definition. So I put `MacroImpl` and `Macros` in one subproject and called the macro in another and it worked perfectly.

Thanks to Dmytro for taking the time to demonstrate how to do it right!

// edit: looks like Dmytro beat me to it with his comment :-)